# Set Associative Cache vs Direct Mapped Cache how do I understand preformance differences

Tags: caching

I've been trying to review caches recently and I find myself struggling to understand the difference between these two types of cache when applied in a practical sense. While I understand the idea that a direct mapped cache must directly map and thereby it gets additional conflict misses I don't really see how to predict this in a practical example. For example suppose I have a cache of 2 MB with a blocksize of 64 bytes and I run the following loop.

```
int s, A[1024][2048], B[2048][1024]; s = 0;
 for (i=0; i<1024; i++) 
   for (j=0; j<2048; j++)
      s += A[i][j]+B[j][i];
```

;

If I want to calculate the number of cache misses which occur running it with a direct mapped cache vs a fully associative cache vs a 16 way set associative cache I don't understand how they will actually behave differently. My understanding is that for all three options accessing A[i][j] essentially has a 1/16 miss rate and B[j][i] will miss 1/2 of the time because despite its suboptimal access pattern its able to retain B[j] accesses for one cycle due to the size of memory. However this all feels really wrong to me and I feel as though the three different styles of cache should have different miss rates. If someone could help me through this example I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!